# argv[] always returns the same integer

Tags: c, gcc

I am attempting to make a simple dice program. The program can run 2 ways: Either by using `scanf()` to get the amount of dice needed to be rolled, or by passing the amount of dice to be rolled as an argument.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if !defined(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)
    #error CLOCK_MONOTONIC is not defined
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc > 2){
        printf("\nExpected exactly one argument, received %d\n", argc);
        return 1;
    } else if (argc == 1){
        void Randomize() {

            struct timespec tmp;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tmp);
            srand(tmp.tv_nsec);

        }

        int Random(int Max) {

            return ( rand() % Max)+ 1;

        }

        int amount;
        printf("Enter the amount of dice to roll: ");
        scanf( "%d", &amount );
        printf("\nYou entered: %d ", amount);
        printf("\n");
        Randomize();
        int i;
        int totals[6];
        for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
        totals[ i ]=0;
        for (i=0;i<amount;i++) {

            int d=Random(6) ;
            int total=d;
            totals[ total ]++;

        }

        for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {

            printf("%i %i\n\r",i,totals[ i ]) ;

        }
    } else {

        int amount = *argv[1];
        printf("Getting dice: %d\n", amount);
        void Randomize() {

            struct timespec tmp;
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tmp);
            srand(tmp.tv_nsec);

        }

        int Random(int Max) {

            return ( rand() % Max)+ 1;

        }

        Randomize();
        int i;
        int totals[6];
        for (i=1;i<=6;i++)
        totals[ i ]=0;
        for (i=0;i<amount;i++) {

            int d=Random(6) ;
            int total=d;
            totals[ total ]++;

        }

        for (i=1;i<=6;i++) {

            printf("%i %i\n\r",i,totals[ i ]) ;

        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The first and second portions of the code works as intended. That is, if parsing more than one argument (in addition to the program name itself) the program will exit with intended message. 
If not parsing an argument (in addition to the program name itself) the program also works as intended.

The issue is with the third portion of code, wherein I should be able to use `./a.out 123` to get 123 random dice. 
When I try this method, I receive:

```
Getting dice: 49
1 8
2 10
3 6
4 7
5 7
6 11
```

as the output, regardless of what argument I pass.

Why is 49 always the amount specified, regardless of the argument passed, and how can I modify the program to get the correct integer as an argument?

Edit: Formatting x2

Comment: `argv[1]` is a string; you need to convert it to a number with `strtol()` or `atoi()`.  You’re taking the first character of the string, probably a value in the range 49..57.

Comment: Why do you repeat code for functions?

Comment: Here's an [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). Notice that the digit `'1'` is encoded as 49 in ASCII.

Comment: @Yunnosch I likely don't. This is what I threw together since I started with only the `scanf()` implementation. Copy and paste the entire blocks was quicker for testing purposes.

Comment: Is there a built-in way to make argv[1] an int rather than a char?

Comment: Spectacular_Vernacular: The standard library functions to use are in @JonathanLeffler's first comment. (I'd strongly suggest using the first one, `strtol()`).